# PerformancePoint Service Application is not available in New Service Applications drop down

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, performancepoint

I have installed SharePoint Server 2016 in 3 Tier Architecture (Configuration database version: 16.0.4456.1000). When I am trying to configure PerformancePoint Service, I don't find the PerformancePoint Service Application in New Service Applications drop down. I am following below Technet article to configure PerformancePoint Service.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748644(v=office.16).aspx#Anchor_2

Did anybody face this issue? Please let me know the resolution.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performqncepoint service application is part of enterprise edition of SharePoint server. Please check and make sure you are using the enterprise edition.

From central admin > upgrade and migration > convert license type...this will tell u what edition ur are using.

You can try this script.https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/40031.sharepoint-2016-detect-the-installed-edition-with-powershell.aspx

Also, could you please share what minrole you are using for each server.

Comment: I am using below min role.

Content Farm Topology: Small Non-High Availability MinRole farm
Two servers with two shared roles:
- One Front-end with Distributed Cache server.
- One Application with Search server.

Are there any steps if I had to change to Enterprise edition?

Comment: My current license is "SharePoint Server Trial with Standard Client Access License"

Comment: So licensing is your problem, you have to convert your license from standard to enterprise.check this link http://krossfarm.com/?p=1553